# Neo4j advanced mapping SDN

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

WE have been using basic neo4j SDN repository.save() for saving a large number of entities in one shot using bolt driver. However, it is taking more time than we anticipated. JUst came across the same queries in StackOverflow and found "advanced mapping with neo4j" is faster. Can anyone explain or provide some links for the same?

[save method of CRUDRepository is very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568203/save-method-of-crudrepository-is-very-slow)

[Spring Data Neo4j: why save method takes so long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842185/spring-data-neo4j-why-save-method-takes-so-long)

Answer (score 0):

figured out one reason that made graph DB queries slow,

We were using @Transactional for the method that involved "lock" operations. ANd that made slow

Execution time w/o @Transactional: 30 seconds
Execution time with @Transactional: around 4 mins

We then implemented manual locking strategy! still, 30 seconds is so much for a single graph DB query. Looking forward to some inputs to optimise further.